# How to provide space between two strings in es6

Tags: javascript

I want to provide space between name and age , so i have used `\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0` its working fine, But it not looks good is there another way to implement this

```
personsList: `${t('Name')} ${personName}\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0${t('age')} ${personAge}
```

Comment: What is the output type? Monospace console? HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess at some point you're rendering `personsList` to HTML and you want more than just one space in between the name and the following age, which is why you're using non-breaking spaces rather than just normal spaces.

One approach if that's true is to refactor slightly and put the name and age information in different elements with appropriate padding and such.

If you absolutely have to do it via text, what you have is workable. You've said it doesn't look good. You could make it more explicit by using a constant for the non-breaking space, and perhaps using [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```
const nbsp = "\u00A0";
// ...
personsList: `${t('Name')} ${personName}${nbsp.repeat(3)}${t('age')} ${personAge}
```

Or similar, but with a defined spacer.

```
const spacer = "\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0";
// ...
personsList: `${t('Name')} ${personName}${spacer}${t('age')} ${personAge}
```

But I'd recommend refactoring as described above instead.